# Github can execute workflow successfully but GitHub Pages gets `404 File not found error`

Tags: blazor

Here is my github repo - https://github.com/ngaisteve1/blazor-maps and I could run it successfully locally.

Then, I push the code to github and uses workflow to auto build and deploy the page, it could run all the workflow steps successfully

- Set up job (Passed)
- Run actions/checkout@v2 (Passed)
- Setup .NET Core (Passed)
- Publish with dotnet (Passed)
- Deploy to Github Pages (Passed)
- Post Run actions/checkout@v2 (Passed)
- Complete job (Passed)

But when I run the page, https://ngaisteve1.github.io/blazor-maps/, it gives me `404 File not found error`

Comment: Ask to JamesIves

Comment: Your log said : There is nothing to commit. Exiting early…

Comment: Thanks. May I know where you see the log, nothing to commit?

Comment: I managed to solve it but only with Blazor Web Assembly project but not Blazor Server project.

Comment: You cannot deploy an ASP.Net Core Project on github page. Github is a static file server, it doesn't execute anything

Comment: A saw the log in the action log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it but only with Blazor Web Assembly project but not Blazor Server project. I think Blazor Server doesn't work because it requires it to be run in the server.